# SSIS Lookup join and SQL join

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

Joining  2 tables using the ssis lookup would result only the first matching output,rather than all the matching output in SQL.Is there any way to code SSIS ,to result out all the 
matching out put.

Table 1

```
Country,Prate,year
uk,1%,2014
France,1%,2014
```

Table 2

```
Country,SSrate,year
uk,11%,2014
uk,22%,2013
France,15%,2014
```

The ssis result, with the joining column as country would be

```
   Country,Prate,year,ssrate
    uk,1%,2014,11%
    France,1%,2014,15%
```

How to get a result as shown below

```
Country,Prate,year,ssrate
uk,1%,2014,11%
uk,1%,2013,22%
France,1%,2014,15%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eyeballing it, I would reverse your operations.

I would have an OLE DB Source set as Table2 and then use Table 1 in a Lookup Component. Thus, every row from Table 2 makes it to the destination with data from Table 1 appended to it.

If there is data in table 1 that needs to make it to the target, you'd need to update the question to indicate all the cases you need to deal with. But, the answer at that point would probably be something like [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77666/ssis-get-max-value-in-column-and-create-new-column/77685#77685)